# mysqli: how to get the type of a column in a table

Tags: php, mysqli

How can i get the type of a column in a table, e.g. datetime, int(32) or varchar(40)?
i have got a result, that is fetched into an object, the vardump prints:

```
object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  public 'email' => string 'me@foo.bar' (length=6)
```

id should be an integer and email a varchar(i).
I am working with php5 and mysqli.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get that information, you need to query the information_schema.columns table.  Something like this will get the MySQL data type:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'
```

Comment: SELECT `DATA_TYPE`  FROM `COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE 'DATABASENAME' AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'user' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'id'
thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Given that the question is about *mysqli*, there is no reason to do this separate query - see [Hazem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22588912/199364).

Comment: a.f.a.i.k  it is called `COLUMN_TYPE` and not `DATA_TYPE` but the rest is correct.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using mysqli, which I highly recommend for so many reasons, it will be as easy as

```
$query = "SELECT * from " . $table_name;

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    // Get field information for all columns
    while ($column_info = $result->fetch_field()){
        echo $column_info->type;
    }
}
```

That would print out some numbers, these numbers indicate the type of each column as following:

### numerics

BIT: 16

TINYINT: 1

BOOL: 1

SMALLINT: 2

MEDIUMINT: 9

INTEGER: 3

BIGINT: 8

SERIAL: 8

FLOAT: 4

DOUBLE: 5

DECIMAL: 246

NUMERIC: 246

FIXED: 246

### dates

DATE: 10

DATETIME: 12

TIMESTAMP: 7

TIME: 11

YEAR: 13

### strings & binary

CHAR: 254

VARCHAR: 253

ENUM: 254

SET: 254

BINARY: 254

VARBINARY: 253

TINYBLOB: 252

BLOB: 252

MEDIUMBLOB: 252

TINYTEXT: 252

TEXT: 252

MEDIUMTEXT: 252

LONGTEXT: 252

And for more information about fetch_field check this out https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was looking for such an approach forever and this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: LIMIT 1? maybe.

Comment: the type/ number mapping is fantastic. thx.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment to get the data type, you can run the query `DESC tablename`, and iterate over the resultset, which will give you data on each column in the table.

This would give you everything for a table, you can of course modify Patrick's answer to do the same (or if you want it to return this more specifically).

Answer (score -1):

Everything that php gets from the database is always of type `string`

Comment: or `null`, don't forget that ;-)

Comment: yes, i know, but how could i get the type in the database? is there a sql-statement i could send?

Answer (score -2):

> how can i get the type of a column in a table, e.g. datetime, int(32) or varchar(40)?

obviously you don't need it.

> id should be an integer and email a varchar

Well - you have to ask so. Just use prepared statement with mysqli

```
$stm = $db->prepare("select 1 `int`, 'str' `string`, NULL `NULL`");
$stm->execute();
$res = $stm->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($row);

array(3) {
  ["int"]=>
  int(1)
  ["string"]=>
  string(3) "str"
  ["NULL"]=>
  NULL
}
```