# How to get table structure and its data through mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am doing a project where I do not have the access to phpmyadmin. I want to see the structure and data of a table. How can I do that using mysql query? I used `DESCRIBE tablename` but that only displayed the list of columns. Any ideas? I can use another query `SELECT * FROM tablename` but I just want to know where is there any command that would serve the purpose? I also need to know the **type** of my table columns.

Comment: https://www.adminer.org/ use this single page php application. Hope this will help you..

Comment: Describe does what you are asking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of columns for a table, use the DESCRIBE SQL statement. DESCRIBE provides information about the columns in a table:  The syntax is as follows:

```
DESCRIBE TableName
```

ex. `DESCRIBE products;` will give:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| url         | varchar(100)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(10,2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| visible     | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

To get a list of tables on the database, use this SQL statement:

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Retrieving the Table Definition of an Existing Table

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName;
```

Also check this link for more commands related to MySQL tables: [MySQL Table Commands](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/table-commands/)

Comment: I want column names, their types and its complete data.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysqli_fetch_fields`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) can be used to get the metadata for a `mysqli_result` response.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from foo");

$meta = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
foreach ($meta as $column) {
    echo "Name: {$column->name}\n";
    echo "Table: {$column->table}\n";
    echo "Max. Len: {$column->max_length}\n";
    echo "Length: {$column->length}\n";
    echo "charsetnr: {$column->charsetnr}\n";
    echo "Flags: {$column->flags}\n";
    echo "Type: {$column->type}\n";
}

$result->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
      echo "{$name} = {$value}\n";
    }
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

[`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) provides a similar functionality for a [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) query.

Comment: column->type returns integer like 3 or 253 or 254 etc. How to get type like int, varchar, book is.in words etc?

Comment: @AVA Take a look at the `MYSQLI_TYPE_*` constants at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php

Comment: got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824722/mysqli-how-to-get-the-type-of-a-column-in-a-table explains well and also refers http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php!

Answer (score 1):

```
EXPLAIN table_name
```

This will display the details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

ought to get you started. See Chapter 20 in the MySQL documentation.